# SpeechSynthesisUtterance to use other voice than native

Tags: speech-synthesis

Trying to change the voice from `native` to `Google US English` without success. This is the code I am using:

https://jsfiddle.net/uv2k0qws/

```
function speak(text) {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    msg.volume = 1;
    msg.rate = 1;
    msg.pitch = 2;
    msg.text = text;
    msg.lang = "en-US";
    msg.name = "Google US English";
    msg.voiceURI = "Google US English"
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
speak('Attention! This is a test.');
```

Any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

    utterance.onstart = function (event) {
        console.log('The utterance started to be spoken.')
    };

    window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function () {

        voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        utterance.voice = voices.filter(function (voice) { return voice.lang == 'pt-BR'; })[0];

    }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        utterance.text = "Bom dia amigos!";
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that setting `utterance.voice` is not enough on Android Chrome. Though it seems to work on all other platforms. You must also set `utterance.lang`. Here's a snippet, which you might have to run twice in the console to see it work because `speechSynthesis.getVoices` is loaded lazily.

```
let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("hello");
let voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()[0]
utterance.voice = voice; // required for iOS
utterance.lang = voice.lang; // required for Android Chrome
utterance.voiceURI = voice.voiceURI;
speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```